# Avoiding .gitignore on one folder

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a .gitignore file on my repository to prevent uploading some files.

But I want to have a single folder inside this repository where all kind of files are allowed.

How can I scape the gitignore on that folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can negate patterns in `.gitignore`, causing otherwise excluded files to be included.

```
!folderX/**/*
```

A line like this in `.gitignore` will "unexclude" all files in `folderX` and its subfolders.

Note: The `.gitignore` file is parsed from top to bottom. *Add this line at the end*.
Any rule that comes after this line can override its effect.